# webintent　プラグインでメールを生成すると一部メールアプリで文字化けしてしまう

Tags: javascript, android, monaca, gmail

monacaでスマホアプリ開発中です。
アプリ内でフローチャートを作り、「Yes」「NO」などの回答をテキスト出力してメールソフトを起動し、メール本文に表示させています。

andoroid端末はmailtoが使えなかった(メーラが起動しない）ため、android向けにはwebintentプラグインを利用しています。

メーラーの起動等はできるのですが、端末内で起動するメールソフト(docomoキャリアメール、Gmailなど）によってメール本文が文字化けを起こしています。
現在下記で問題ないのはGmailです。docomoメールでは文字化けします。
コメントアウトしている部分を生かすと、docomoはOKですが、Gmailで文字化けします。
どうしたらいいでしょうか？

```
    function android_mailto(){            
        var hiduke = new Date();
        var year = hiduke.getFullYear();
        var month = hiduke.getMonth()+1;
        var day = hiduke.getDate();
        var hour = hiduke.getHours()
        var minute = hiduke.getMinutes();
        var subject = year + "年" + month + "月" + day + "日" + hour + "時" + minute + "分";
        //var result = unescape(encodeURIComponent(body));
        var result = body

        window.plugins.webintent.startActivity (
                {
                    action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    url: 'mailto:?subject=' + subject + "&body=" + result
                },
                function () {},
                function () {alert ('Failed to open URL via Android Intent');}
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決いたしましたのでご報告します。

改行コードを(ios）%0D%0A から(android)\x0D\x0Aに変えたら文字化けしなくなりました。

みなさま、ありがとうございました。